# Вставить символ в строку через заданное количество символов

Tags: php

Всем привет есть строка типа 53763badd6f05.

Нужно прогнать через php что бы была строка 53763-badd-6f05. Т.Е. С тире.

Как это делается?

Comment: По какому условию ставиться тире?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$a = "53763badd6f05";
$a = substr($a, 0, 5)."-".substr($a, 5, 4)."-".substr($a, 9, 4);
echo $a;
```

или так:

```
$a = "53763badd6f05";
$a = substr_replace($a, "-", 5, 0);
$a = substr_replace($a, "-", 10, 0);
echo $a;
```

ну или даже так (это к вопросу про условие):

```
$a = "53763badd6f05";
$a = preg_replace("/badd/", "-$0-", $a);
echo $a;
```

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно вставить символ в строку через определенное количество символов.

```
$a = "53763badd6f0553763badd6f0553763badd6f0553763badd6f05dfg";
$len = strlen($a);
$counter = 0;
$placeToAddSymbol = 0;
for($i = 0;$i != $len; $i++){
    // $counter - количество символов
    if($counter == 5){
        if($placeToAddSymbol == 0){
            $placeToAddSymbol = $placeToAddSymbol + $counter;
        }
        else{
            $placeToAddSymbol = $placeToAddSymbol + $counter + 1;
        }
        $a = substr_replace($a, "-", $placeToAddSymbol, 0);
        $counter = 0;
    }
    $counter++;
}

echo $a;
```

Вернет 53763-badd6-f0553-763ba-dd6f0-55376-3badd-6f055-3763b-add6f-05dfg

Answer (score 1):

Есть встроенная в PHP функция:

```
chunk_split('53763badd6f05', 5, '-')
```