# Пробел между словами в строке в php

Tags: php

Как сделать пробел между словами в строке? Например строка NewMovie в итоге должно получиться New Movie. Т.е. пробел должен вставляться перед каждой заглавной буквой в строке. Допустим на питоне можно проверить код символа, чтобы узнать нужный символ, а как сделать на php?

Comment: 1) сформулируйте точное условие, по которому искать место для вставки (подстрока, порядковый номер символа, что-то ещё и тд) 2) http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/320634/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если интересует только латиница, то можно **примерно**  так:

```
$s = "SomeCamelCaseString";
$s = ltrim(preg_replace( '/[A-Z]/', ' $0', $s ));
print $s; // "Some Camel Case String"
```

Или, с учётом локали, **примерно** так:

```
$s = rtrim( preg_replace_callback
     (
        '/\w/',
        function( $matches )
        {
            return ctype_upper($matches[0]) ? ' '.$matches[0] : $matches[0];
        },
        $s
     ) );
```

Примерно - потому что в такой строке мы не проверим, что пробел уже есть и вставим второй перед `C`: "camel Case".

Comment: А что делать с аббревиатурами вида CNN, BBC?:)
print preg_replace('/([a-z])([A-Z])/', '$1 $2', 'CamelCaseBCC');

Comment: А в условии что-то оговаривалось про такие случаи? Думаю, при наличии головы на плечах автор вопроса сам додумает что ещё нужно будет.

Comment: Согласен! Это всего лишь дополнение к вашему ответу:)

Comment: BTW, `([a-z])([A-Z])` проблем с локалью не решает :(

Comment: Так в вашем же сообщении есть решение :)

Comment: Но в нём не учитываются предшествующие буквы.